# File based hash data structure

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement to compare a "key" of each records(around 1m records) against 70m+ records in DB.

I really don't want to hit the DB again and again to compare.

when I try to load all the keys (just keys) from DB to in memory (hashTable), I am getting out of memory exceptions randomly on other parts of program (as I expected).

is there any file based implementation of hash table instead of in-memory?

Comment: DBs are made to read. Any other solution you're thinking of is very strange.. why can't you simply read it in iterations? If you can't do that, you need to do the operations you want in database-code (presumably SQL). Or get more memory..

Comment: The current system SQL DB server's runs on SAN disks, many production systems are running over there, its expensive. i am looking for file based DB which can run on cheap servers. Something like MS Access, but it was very slow for this requirement. even tried Local SQL server, its slower. I am looking for faster look up but file based. Just an implementation of HASH table instead inmemory it should be file based. I dont need any other features such as RDMS features.

Answer (score 3):

Create a temporary table in the DB and write all the 1m keys to it. Then, use a query to compare the keys in the temp table with the ones in the target table - this will be relatively fast since SQL engines are really good at joining. Since you only need results for 1m keys, the query will return 1m rows(instead of 70m), and you can also stream that result(since it already contains the matches).

Comment: Thanks, but I really dont want to invoke this comparison on SQL side where i have 70m records, because its a production system, many users are connected to DB server. However i could try this in new local DB, but again we have to have a new SQL instance on local. let me try with SQL express on local server. Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of installing SQL Server locally, you can use [SQL Server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/compact.aspx) - a file-based version of SQL Server. Anyways, unless your comparison is very very heavy, it'll be less resource-consuming for your production SQL Server to do the join locally than to serve 70m rows to another process.

Comment: I will try, I tried SQL Lite. But it was slower.

Comment: I second that - you can also index the 1M rows, indexing is essentially a way of hashing (not really but performance is very very close to hash)

Comment: I believe SQLite is faster than SQL Server CE(as long as your remember to use transactions!). At any rate, your main problem is transferring 70m rows over the network, and that's not something a good selection of local SQL engine can solve...

Comment: @StenPetrov I'm not sure indexing the 1M rows will make them faster. The query needs to iterate through each one of the 1M rows anyways(since we need a match result for each), and the temp table will only be read once and then dropped once the connection is closed, so indexing them is a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks @Idan Arye

your Response made me thinking of temp DB on app server side.

I have compared SQLLite, SQL Server CE,MS Access. They are slower when inserting a row, and while comparing the value.

Finally I found a DB called ESENT, It is Windows In build DB, Rocking performance. The inserting part now takes less than 30 min, and comparision is just like looking at in-memory data structure. However it is every complex to use.
There is a managed interface available at codeplex
http://managedesent.codeplex.com/